# Prevent text wrap of single word in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

Is is possible to turn off text wrapping for a single word inside a text in React Native? Similar to `span { white-space: nowrap }`.

I've already tried to set `numberOfLines` together with multiple styles, but non of them helps.

```
<Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <Text numberOfLines={ 1 } styles={ { flexWrap: 'nowrap' } }>should/not/wrap</Text> sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore.</Text>
```

`should/not/wrap` should always appear in one line. It currently breaks at `/` (depending on the screen size).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074659/react-native-avoid-text-wrapping .

Comment: This only works when you have two text components. It doesn't work when you want to avoid text wrapping for a single word inside a text.

Comment: ohhh , i get it .   I don't know if will work in react-native but maybe try this : https://css-tricks.com/where-lines-break-is-complicated-heres-all-the-related-css-and-html/#article-header-id-2